# Batch updates across multiple docs in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Google Firestore, I have an author collection:

```
author {
   id: 1,
   name: 'rob',
   pic:'http://pics.com/rob'
}
```

I also have a blogpost:

```
blogpost{
   id:'a',
   text: '...',
   authorid: 1
   authorname: 'rob',
   authorpic:'http://pics.com/rob'
}
```

I copied authorid/name/pic into the blogpost so I didn't need to fetch author names/pics on every return of a blogpost.

However, now I need to implement a name change feature which means I need to search for all blogposts and update the author name.

Two questions:

1. Given author name doesn't update frequently, do you think this is the right pattern?
2. whats the best way to update author details across all my blog posts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to get references to all the user's posts and update the documents. Another possibility is to fetch author's name from author's info itself rather than storing the name in all posts so you only need to update that doc. But since reads are way more frequent than write, it'll be best to store names in all blog posts and update them.

I'd recommend storing IDs of author's posts in an array in author document so you can get references to all of author's posts directly and don't spend *N* reads to get IDs of author's posts (N is number of posts).

Comment: While I agree with storing a "post index" somewhere, I would nest it under the author's main document rather than place it inside it. You wouldn't want to pull every post ID they've ever made if you only needed the author's display name, username and profile image. I'd also highlight how this feature might be better suited to making use of Cloud Functions to action the change so permissions won't cause problems and could also be used to apply profanity filters before making any changes. I would also consider adding some code samples or relevant documentation links to this answer.

Comment: Good comment, thank you.